# R box-cox transformation to logarithmic transformation

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am very new to language R and trying to learn through small projects. I have applied box-cox transformation to my data set

```
m <- lm(PartB_DV ~ PartB_IV)
library(MASS)
bc <- boxcox(PartB_DV ~ PartB_IV)
#plot(bc)
(lambda <- bc$x[which.max(bc$y)])
```

I found lambda between (0,1) so I have to apply logarithmic transformation. Yet, I had no idea how to proceed and did something like:

```
m.log= lm(log(PartB_DV)~PartB_IV)
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track so, I wanted to ask what is the right way to transform my independent and dependent data set logarithmically

Comment: The Box-Cox transformation gives you the lambda power that when applied to your dependent variable can help to stabilize your variance for linear modeling assumptions. Values close to zero imply a log transformation. You say you found a value between 0 and 1, but if the value was 0.5, then you should do a square root transformation not a log, for example. If you did find a lambda close to zero then the code you shared would be fine for applying a log transformation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My obtained lambda value was exactly -0.1818182. My goal is to find the ratio of the transformation to apply something like ~~~data_trans <- data.frame(xtrans=data$x, ytrans=data$y^(-3/2)) ~~~ (-3/2 transformation here)

Comment: `lm(y^lambda ~ x)` would give you the most normal independent variable given your data. However, the difficulty can arise when trying to interpret coefficients on this transformed variable.